# How to troubleshoot cors error on IIS server

Tags: c#, angular, iis, cors, signalr

I'm working on an application which the backend is a net core API with SignalR and the front end is Angular. Debugging on my computer it works as expected but when I publish on the server it shows Cors error even after enabling them on the startup.cs.

This is the error Im getting:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://server:10079/fareg/api/account' from origin 'http://server' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Can anyone please help to identify what I'm doing wrong to get ride of the CORS error?

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        //add Windows authentication for http options request
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        services.AddDbContext<FAContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FADB")));

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: _MyCors, builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => new Uri(origin).Host == "server name")
                    //.WithOrigins("http://server/fareg", "http://localhost:4200")
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    //.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });

        services.AddSignalR().AddMessagePackProtocol();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseCors(_MyCors);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
       {
           routes.MapHub<Hubs.HubFA>("/signalr");
       });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you enabled Windows authentication and use IIS, the simplest option is to use IIS CORS module to allow preflight requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you put the UseCors() in a wrong place. Try to use this syntax

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy(_MyCors,
                      builder =>
                       {
                       builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowAnyHeader();
              }));

        .....
            
        }

        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            .....

           // app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(_MyCors);

         //  app.UseAuthorization();
         // app.UseEndpoints(..
 
         }
```

Make sure that UseCors should be in the end of Configure method but before UseAuthorizaton. In  your case it should be just above UseMvc(). But AddCors should be moved to the top of Configure services.

If this syntax is working for you, only after this you can try to add useorigin.